# Use Application Insight with ASP API Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Community

I'm having troubles connecting Application Insights to my ASP WEB API Core. 
Following standard manuals I still cannot find any record in my AppInsights account. 
I used a lot of manuals, but the are pretty identical and describe how to configure App Insights for ASP Core (not API Core). 
So I'm wondering is some special configuration (or nuget package or whatever) is required to make AppInsights track requests to my API service?

Once I cannot make AppInsights work out of box, I still can create instance of TelemetryClient and publish data manually, but this is not desirable in my case.

Important note: I'm using VS 2017 RC, Web APi Core project (csproj)

UPD

csproj file content:

```
  <Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild1-update1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild1-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-update1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild1-update1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild1-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-update1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen" Version="6.0.0-beta901" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi" Version="6.0.0-beta901" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Configuration in Startup.cs:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(true);
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Trace);
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Error);

            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: Just FYI: there is no such thing as ASP.NET Web API Core. MVC and Web API have been merged into ASP.NET Core MVC. Could you show us some code with the logging and your csproj file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using the "new" asp.net core in VS2017, then the old instructions are wrong, as they are for the previous xproj based asp.net core implementations.

If you create a *new* asp.net core web project in VS2017, ApplicationInsights will be already installed from the start, and should be versions:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
```

*(or newer, if the asp.net core team has updated them at all)*

Those projects will already have Application Insights wired up as well, not in Startup.cs (that's the old way), but in Program.cs:

```
new WebHostBuilder()
   ...
   .UseApplicationInsights() // this starts up appinsights in asp.net core now
   ...
   .UseOtherThings();
```

and possibly in web templates, like:

```
 @inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
```

at the top, and

```
 @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
```

inside the bottom of the `<head>` tag.

if you're migrating from a previous version of asp.net core and app insights, you'll also have to remove things like:

```
@Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)
```

from _Layout.cshtml and replace them with the lines above, and you can remove all of the lines like:

app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

in Startup.cs (if you're using 2.x versions of the packages, i believe those items will all show deprecation warnings as well, as they're no longer needed)

VS2017's official release notes include this information as a section in the ["known issues" for application insights](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#KIAppInsights)

Comment: for a MVC web api (VS2017 Web Api project /MVC core 1.1), is it just a matter of adding the InstrumentationKey in the appsettings.json?

Comment: if you created it in VS2017, then yes, AI should be already included in the project and you should just need to set the ikey, either by setting it by hand in appsettings.json, or by right click the project, choose `configure application insights` and there's UI to set that up.

Comment: After hours of searching this finally allowed me to get App Insights working for an Asp.Net Core Web API application in Azure - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved thanks to this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35918.asp-net-core-1-0-configure-application-insights.aspx#STEP_4_Configure_Application_Insights_into_your_Web_Application)

There are 2 points I missed in my configuration:
1. In csproj should be referenced package "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0-beta1"
2. In class Startup, method Configure I missed to add app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

When I changed what described above AppInsights has started to track all requests

Comment: I read somewhere that we're supposed to use the `Program.cs` method and not the `Configure` method for adding this.  I had them in both and was getting double the telemetry.